# Chrome not loading the latest html files

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am running a webserver on *localhost:1234*
The HTML file that is getting loaded is -

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
        <a href="/anthrax/help.html">Help Page</a><br>
        <a href="/anthrax/news.html">News Page</a>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
    </script>
</html>
```

whereas the actual HTML file is :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
        <a href="/anthrax/help.html">Help Page</a><br>
        <a href="/anthrax/news.html">News Page</a>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url"); -->

    </script>
</html>
```

The commented part should have been removed.
Tried

1. Disable cache in Network tab of Developer options
2. Restarting the server

None of these resolved the issue.
What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: FYI: If you use `CTRL + F5` you're also loading the page unchached. Also you should use javascript comments in `<script></script>`. You can do this with `/* multiline comment*/` or with `//comment`.

Comment: If you are still working on this file, close the source file if is open in any code edtor. Open the file again and check if you are working on correct file.

Comment: OMG!! I missed it. I am working on incorrect file. There were files with the exact same name and path in another Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use HTML comments inside JavaScript, try to use `//`  inline or `/* ... */` multi-line comments.